# What is mango-gw in route's man?

Tags: networking, router, gateway

What is the purpose of specifying *mango-gw* as a gateway?
Here is short excerpt from manual.

```
route add default gw mango-gw
              adds  a  default  route  (which  will be used if no other route matches).  All packets using this route will be gatewayed through "mango-gw". The device
              which will actually be used for that route depends on how we can reach "mango-gw" - the static route to "mango-gw" will have to be set up before.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's in the "Examples" session. It's an *example*. It shows how you could add a default gateway. Supposedly you have a computer named `mango-gw` which you want to use as the default gateway. You could as well ask what's the purpose of specifying `192.57.66.0` in the example for `route add -net` a few lines down.